# ASP.NET Web Site - Unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is it possible to do any unit testing with an ASP.NET Web site (not a project or application)? If so, how can I implement them. If not, what options do I have (convert to web app, no unit testing, etc)?

It doesn't appear it is possible (or is fairly difficult) but I'd like to see what other options are available.

Comment: Generally most Web Forms applications are written so that a lot of the logic is embedded in event handlers, which are difficult to unit test. If you were to extract as much as possible into separate class libraries, that would simplify testing.

Comment: If it's an existing site then the chances are slim. Code tends to lean toward untestable if it wasn't written with testability in mind. You can ensure that to the extent possible new code is written in testable classes. Write your .aspx code-behind so that it does nothing but invoke other classes since the code-behind itself is hard to test.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I tried creating a very simple webform which uses an orchestrator class to read values from its inputs and update other controls accordingly. It technically works and makes the page somewhat testable. But a) it's a pain to write. b) there's no telling what sort of properties on form controls could cause a runtime error, effectively making the test useless, and c) it's hard to imagine how ugly this could get if the page had to do anything more substantial.

Comment: @Scott Unfortunately, I figured that might be the case. Thanks for trying that out

Comment: ASP.NET MVC tends to be far more unit testable, and Web Forms is a dying framework anyways. I suggest you migrate away from it.